# Facelets produce excesive XHTML markup

Tags: java, xhtml, facelets

Is it possible to tell Facelets to not expand every possible element? perfectly to leave it as it was? If I have for example:

```
<br/><span class="fa fa-warn"/>
```

It produces:

```
<br /><span class="fa fa-warn"></span>
```

Comment: The top example is incorrect XHTML. Non-void elements like `span` are not supposed to be shortened to self-closing start tags. So even if it were possible, why would you want to generate incorrect output?

Comment: It is valid and they can be shortened - who told you they can not?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/guidelines.html#C_3 says "Given an empty instance of an element whose content model is not **`EMPTY`** (for example, an empty title or paragraph) do not use the minimized form (e.g. use `<p> </p>` and not `<p />`)."

Comment: Please read the header of the appendix you specified. It's not the XHTML standard, just a guideline for backward-compatibility with HTML. XHTML is XML, unless XML Schema specifies explicitely that element can't be mninified, it can and AFAIK no element in XHTML is forbidden to be minified.